# Using user editable image URL in application. Security issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, validation, xss, assets

I am writing an application where users are required to show their photo, however as my server resources are very limited I can not let them upload it to the server.

So I have three major questions:

**1. How to properly validate photo URL?** At least I can validate with regexp, however I need to check for file ending:

```
`validates_format_of :photo_url, :with => URI::regexp(%w(http https))`
```

**2. Security issues? XSS?**

Even I validate the picture at the moment of creation, hacker can replace image with malicious stuff anytime.

**3. Maybe there are free asset stores with API?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. How to properly validate photo URL?**

You can use a plugin that validates the format of an URL or write it your self:

```
  validates_each :photo_url do |record, attr, value|
    begin
      uri = URI::parse(value)
      record.errors.add(nil, 'Sorry, you may only use http/https links') if (uri.class.to_s =~ /URI::HTTPS?/).nil?
      record.errors.add(nil, 'The url must point to a picture') unless value =~ /\.(png|jpg|jpeg)$/i
    rescue URI::InvalidURIError
      record.errors.add(nil, 'The format of the url is not valid')
    end
  end
```

**2. Security issues? XSS?**

There aren't any outstanding security issues as long as you escape the text.
`<%=h image_tag obj.photo_url %>` is safe.
Take in mind, that the user can still use a 100MB image that will slow down every visitor.

**3. Maybe there are free asset stores with API?**

There aren't any that I know of, but rackspace cloud, amazon s3 hosting is pretty cheap. 
Some image upload plugins have support for these two, so you'll at least save some time.